# Anaconda prompt closes automatically

Tags: python, anaconda

[screenshot of prompt before it closes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6QQe.png)

the anaconda prompt closes automatically not sure why.
pic of anaconda files after install
[files installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6dwo.png)

I installed the anaconda distrubtion https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section from here version 3.7. I cannot find anaconda app, spyder or jupyter notebook app. I only see files named after them. I tryed uninstalling but to clean out anaconda and properly install again i have been told to remove files left behind when using normal uninstall. So Is there a way to run anaconda clean without anaconda prompt? https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-clean. Im a newb at coding .

Edit: i cannot type anything into the prompt it shows me the picture above before quickly closing.

Comment: Execute it with a command shown on the help page.

Comment: _So Is there a way to run anaconda clean without anaconda prompt?_ The page [Uninstall Anaconda] is rather clear on the matter, I think: _If you also want to remove all traces of the configuration files and directories from Anaconda and its programs, you can download and use the Anaconda-Clean program first, then do a simple remove._ I think your best bet is to remove everything, and start from scratch.

Comment: @AMC  sorry what page is the uninstall anaconda page?

Comment: @Amiy what help page are you referring to?

Comment: @jarjarbinksss the what you see in screenshot, it closes because you give it no command. Open cmd.exe from start menu and try `conda info` if this doesn't work then try `start C:\path\to\_conda.exe info`

Comment: @Amiy i did the "start C:\ etc to _conda.exe info " and it gave me this prompt which closed again very quickly                                                                              " ConfigurationLoaderror: unable to load configuration file". New line                                 
"path: C:\Users\Name\.condarc".New line. "reason: invalid yaml at position 0"

Comment: @Avm-x   the above comment